# Horizontal Menu and Horizontal Submenu

Tags: html, css

I've been trying for a couple of days to write the CSS to make the submenu to be horizontal instead of vertical.

Can someone help me with this?  Hover over Projects.

[Link to page](http://7d1.net/mark/about/)

Thanks in advance...I'm stumped.

Louise

Comment: Please add your code. Also, go into more detail about how you wish the horizontal submenu to look/function. Should it extend to left or right or center on the hovered menu heading? Responsiveness at low screen widths? Wrapping when near edges? Etc.

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Please read this: [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and then create a [mcve] using the snippet button in the wysiwyg

Comment: Sorry, I didn't post any css because nothing works.  Here is the menu code:

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Have you try to search on google? [Try this](https://codepen.io/vichid/pen/cHnmK)